# Can I create an ngResource instance with a method that uses a different route than the rest of the methods?

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I have a standard-ish resource with a basic route definition of `/documents/:id`.  Create / index methods both have nil for id, thus creating a route of just `/documents`.

```
return $resource(apiPath+'documents/:id', {id:'@_id'},{
    index:   { method: 'get', isArray:true, responseType: 'json'},
    show:    { method: 'get', responseType: 'json'},
    update:  { method: 'put', responseType: 'json'},
    create:  { method: 'post', responseType: 'json'}
    // search:  { method: 'post', isArray:true, responseType: 'json'},
    });
```

Unfortunately, I now need to impliment the 'search' method, which needs to POST to `/documents/search`.  The search method actually needs to be distinct from both index and create methods, and contain a message body (so I can include search criteria in excess of the normal GET request limits).

How do I get angular to handle this?

Comment: just add `url` attribute to `search` object

Comment: From angular documents, `url` – {string} – action specific url override. The url templating is supported just like for the resource-level urls.